# Inline CSS is lost after dynamically appending HTML

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, dynamic, inline

I'm using a simple code to dynamically load XML file contents into a div.
The loaded file contains HTML code, with inline CSS.
The file is loaded fine, and can be seen in developer tools, however it loses all the CSS, and you even can't edit the CSS by dev tools.
Weirdly, If I select "Edit as HTML", then add a space and save, the CSS is loaded and works fine!

Firstly, I suspected the file contents and tried different encoding, however this seems to be not the issue.
I also suspected that I need to remove all spaces, did but no use.

I think that CSS isn't applied automatically when appending the code.

Below is the code I used for dynamic loading:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "hadeeth.jpg", dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                var val;
                var now = new Date();
                var cdate = now.getDate() + "-" + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + now.getFullYear();
                var done = false;
                $(xml).find('hadeeth').each(function () {
                    var idate = $(this).find('date').text();
                    val = $(this).find('value').contents();
                    if (idate == cdate)
                    {
                        $('#ahadeeth').html(val);
                        done = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="ahadeeth"></div>
```

Here is a sample content for the loaded div:

```
<div id="ahadeeth"><h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: xx-large;"><strong><span style="font-family: book antiqua,palatino; color: #ff0000;">testing</span></strong></span></h4></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So you're saying you have a jpg image file that you're trying to access as XML, but really it contains HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo He has an XML file with a .jpg suffix (weird). One of the elements of the XML contains HTML (seems OK to me).

Comment: Inserting styled HTML works in a simple case: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ZkaJ7/

Comment: The argument to `.html()` is supposed to be a string. `.contents()` returns jQuery objects, not a string. Maybe it should be `val=$(this).find('value').html()`?

Comment: .JPG is just an extension to workaround .htaccess rules, the contents are pure XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .contents() to .html().  It looks like you want the html inside of the  element, not a jQuery object.

http://api.jquery.com/contents/ 
http://api.jquery.com/html/

EDIT: I did not see your comment Barmar, but I agree with it.

Comment: Thanks much, You pointed me to the right direction.
Unfortunately .html() doesn't work with XML, however the issue indeed was caused by using the jquery object rather than the text.
Further research I was able to solve the issue by encapsulating the data within <![CDATA[your code here]]>.
I got it from a reply on another thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041439/jquery-xml-html-instead-of-text-is-not-displaying

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to using JQuery object rather than the actual text.
The correct way is to use the .text() function to get the actual html code, however it kept returning only the most inner text without any html.

It's supposed to return this:

```
<h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: xx-large;"><strong><span style="font-family: book antiqua,palatino; color: #ff0000;">Test</span></strong></span></h4>
```

however it returns only this:

```
Test
```

The solution was to put the actual HTML code within CDATA tags, so that the parser understand that it should return the whole thing as text, and don't try to parse it.

So instead of having below node in XML:

```
<hadeeth>
<date>3-5-2013</date>
<value><h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: xx-large;"><strong><span style="font-family: book antiqua,palatino; color: #ff0000;">Test</span></strong></span></h4></value>
</hadeeth>
```

I added the CDATA tag, so that it becomes like this:

```
<hadeeth>
<date>3-5-2013</date>
<value><![CDATA[<h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: xx-large;"><strong><span style="font-family: book antiqua,palatino; color: #ff0000;">Test</span></strong></span></h4>]]></value>
</hadeeth>
```

Thanks @Andrew for pointing to the right direction, and for @elektronaut for the use of CDATA tags, in below thread.

[jquery XML .html() instead of .text() is not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041439/jquery-xml-html-instead-of-text-is-not-displaying)